# Put standard wordpress options into a theme options panel?

Tags: theme-options

I'm developing a theme for a client, and I want to allow her to change the site title, description, and her password as needed. However, I don't want to give access to all of the other options (e.g. the site URL).

I have some experience creating a theme options panel (via [this article on nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/)), and was thinking it would be great if I could put those options into the panel as well. Would be great to get some direction!

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach would be to leave the `options-general.php` sub menu unblocked and define:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

in your wp-config.php.  When the siteurl and homeurl are defined in wp-config.php the options are grayed out on the options page.  This would allow your client to change the site title, description, time zone and registration settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just create input fields on your options page and on postback do a"
update_option('blogname') or update_option('blogdescription') with the contents of your custom fields.

Answer (score -1):

Also wondering about this - I tried the following with no luck:

```
// Get setting for site tagline and set it equal to theme option
function of_site_name_tagline_update() { 
   update_option('blogname','$theme_option_blogname');
   update_option('blogdescription','$theme_option_blogdescription'); 
} 
add_action('update_option', 'of_site_name_tagline_update');
```

This is of course assuming my theme option calls are the variables listed above. Even when I enter in a static value - it doesn't update. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!